# IntelliJ: Specify per-project tab size

Tags: tabs, intellij-idea

Is there a way to set the tab size in IntelliJ for a single file only, or at most for a single project?

I use a tab size of 3 for all my code; however, I'm collaborating on a project with an author who prefers a tab size of 4.  Is there a way to set the tab size to 4 for only those files that are part of this project?

Comment: Thanks; you definitely won't be able to set any file-specific configuration options on a file that isn't part of a project loaded in the IDE.  I'm also not aware of any way to set a tab size for a specific file even when it is part of a project in the IDE.  To set a project-specific tab size, please see my answer below.

Comment: I'm just getting burned on this because a javascript library I'm using uses tab size two.  You're making life difficult for yourself by using 3 though - I've never seen that before, 2 and 4 are much more common.

Comment: You should explicitly mention whether you use tabs or spaces in the files. If you use tabs you don't have to change your indentation size at all, for you tabs will look like three characters, for your colleague like four, and neither will notice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open the `Settings` dialog by navigating to `File`->`Settings`.  Under `Project Settings [yourproject]` on the left side of the dialog, navigate to `Code Style`->`General`. The `Tab size` is configurable on that pane, and the value you provide applies only to the project named `yourproject`.

Comment: problem is, this this 4 but still makes 2 within several file types.

Comment: @Panique May be you forgot to change *Java* settings in the *Code Style*

Comment: in top of preferences modal window, in the "Code Style" section, you will find "Scheme" option where you can choose between "Project" and "IDE"

Comment: WebStorm 2019.2: Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> General -> Indents Detection -> uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't answer the initial question.
The answers are:
1. You can not set tab size for a single file.
2. You can set the tab size for a project "IF" your file type is listed  in the "Code Style" specific list of settings.

My case is that I work with typescript files  - and I can not change the tab size.
One would think that for such a basic thing there would be a global setting for all files in a project...

Comment: There is "Other File Types" option but, surprise . . . it doesn't work for .ts files.

Answer (score 3):

for those who can't find `project specific setting`

press `Command + ,` will give you the preference you need

Comment: I think on Windows it is `Crtl + Alt + Shift + S`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global format for the project and "reformat code" to conform to each one's preferred style.

The problem will be your version control system.  If you oil can back and forth between 3 and 4 spaces you'll never be able to see meaningful changes.

Best to settle on one standard and stick to it.

The idea of a private project isn't clear to me.  It comes down to your version control system.  If it's possible to check code in and out so that tab size doesn't affect commits, then I'd say you can be independent.  If you share the common code by adding a compiled 3rd party JAR, then I'd say you can be independent.

Comment: I think @Zack conceded that for the shared project he will need to conform to a tab size of 4 spaces.  In that case, I wouldn't expect there to be any "oil canning back and forth."  The question was whether he can configure his private project to use his preferred tab size of 3 while using the tab size of 4 in the shared project.

Comment: When I say "private project", I mean a project separate from the one that is being worked on with someone else.  This separate project would have its own version control repository, would be a separate project in IntelliJ, would serve some completely different purpose, etc.  That's the scenario I imagined when I read the question.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, now it does.  One last question - how does your project use the fruits of that private project?  Do you get a JAR from him?  Or some other mechanism?

Comment: Only @Zack knows what the relationship between his two projects is, but I was assuming there isn't one whatsoever.

Comment: If that's the case, then there's no need for the question.

Comment: Isn't it possible that @Zack thought he could only configure the tab size as a global setting for all projects in IntelliJ?

Comment: That's the only way I know how to do it.  I would see no reason to do it file by file.

Comment: Here is the long version of the story:  I configure IntelliJ with tab size 3.  I used "private" to describe projects that only I work on, even if they are available for cloning. Recently, I added a feature to a small github project.  Since I was modifying one file only, I used IntelliJ's "Open File" feature to edit the file (instead of creating a project). The project's author objected to his code being re-formated with tab size 3, so I posted here to see if I could get a tab size of 4 for this one "non-project" file.  (I hadn't noticed the "project-specific" option for project settings.)

Comment: In the end, Matt is right:  Creating a project and using project-specific tab size appears to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer to your problem, but IntelliJ can currently (4/2013) "only" handle per-language tab-settings, which is - to be honest - totally okay as language and file type are usually "the same". So this your solve your problem.

You can find the setting in File -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Code Style -> >YOUR LANGUAGE.